# esp-wroom-02のプログラムの書き込みについて

Tags: arduino

現在arduino IDEを使ってesp-wroom-02にプログラムを書き込もうとしているのですが
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
となってしまって書き込むことができません。
一応書き込み時にIO0とRSTをGNDへつないでその他電源も再起動した後に書き込みをしています。これを解決する方法はないでしょうか？どなたか教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

同じようなトラブルに見舞われた方が、解決までの経緯を下のページに書かれています。
[ESPr Developer（ESP-WROOM-02開発ボード）で "warning: espcomm_sync failed" と表示される場合の対処](http://qiita.com/shanonim/items/68fab6dc28b72b31a258)

参考になるのではないでしょうか。